# UIPIckerView showing images and strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView with 3 components, I need the first 2 components to show a string and the third to show an image.  Can I do this by implementing both:

```
- (NSString *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
          forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

Or do I need to create labels and only implement `viewForRow`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
      forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
    {
UILabel *firstLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 60, 32)];
firstLabel.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
firstLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
firstLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UILabel *secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 0, 60, 32)];
secondLabel.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
secondLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
secondLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[countries objectAtIndex:row]]];

UIImageView *icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];        
temp.frame = CGRectMake(170, 0, 30, 30);




UIView *tmpView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 32)] autorelease];
[tmpView insertSubview:icon atIndex:0];
[tmpView insertSubview:firstLabel atIndex:0];
[tmpView insertSubview:secondLabel atIndex:0];
[tmpView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[tmpView setTag:row];
[channelLabel release];
[temp release];
return tmpView;


    }
```